# Creating dynamic object to reorganize API response using Typescript

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, chart.js

**Explanation of what i am doing right now:**

This resembles the data array I get from the API response

```
responseBarDataStacked = [
    { sku: "Data 1", month: "Jun", value: 20 },
    { sku: "Data 2", month: "Jun", value: 25 },
    { sku: "Data 3", month: "Jun", value: 35 },
    { sku: "Data 4", month: "Jun", value: 10 },
    { sku: "Data 5", month: "Jun", value: 10 },
    { sku: "Data 1", month: "Jul", value: 20 },
    { sku: "Data 2", month: "Jul", value: 30 },
    { sku: "Data 3", month: "Jul", value: 15 },
    { sku: "Data 4", month: "Jul", value: 20 },
    { sku: "Data 5", month: "Jul", value: null },
    { sku: "Data 1", month: "Aug", value: 20 },
    { sku: "Data 2", month: "Aug", value: 30 },
    { sku: "Data 3", month: "Aug", value: 15 },
    { sku: "Data 4", month: "Aug", value: 20 },
    { sku: "Data 5", month: "Aug", value: 15 },
];
```

***Note**: this only resembles the data, it does not mean there will be only 5 sets of sku data or 3 months all the time. but is sure that sku or month will not be null.*

I am trying to use this response data on Charts (ng2-chart), for Stacked Bar Graph. For this data to work on Stacked Bar Chart, I needed to format the data with some logic so that I'll get final data as such,

```
{
  data: [20, 25, 35, 10, 10], label: 'Jun', stack: 'sameStack',
  data: [20, 30, 15, 20, null], label: 'Jul', stack: 'sameStack',
  data: [20, 30, 15, 20, 15], label: 'Aug', stack: 'sameStack',
}
```

If you see for data array it is arranged in order as this

```
data: [valueof[Data 1] for month Jun, valueof[Data 2] for month Jun, valueof[Data 3] for month Jun, valueof[Data 3] for month Jun, valueof[Data 5] for month Jun]
```

and so on and so forth for others.

*Why is this particular order??*
*Because if you see below in the method `formatStackedBarData()` uniqueSku is set in FCFS*
i.e.

```
["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 4", "Data 5"]
```

This is the method I am using to format the data accordingly.

```
  formatStackedBarData(dataToFormat: Array<any>) {
    let uniqueMonth = [...new Set(dataToFormat.map(item => item.month))];
    let uniqueSku = [...new Set(dataToFormat.map(item => item.sku))];
    let stackedBarChartData = [];

    uniqueMonth.forEach(month => {
      let uniqueMonthData = dataToFormat
        .filter(barStackData => barStackData.month == month)
        .map(uniqueStackData => uniqueStackData.value);
      stackedBarChartData.push({
        data: uniqueMonthData,
        label: month,
        stack: 'sameStack'
      });
    });

    return {
      stackedBarChartData,
      uniqueSku
    };
  }
```

**Question:**

Now when the response is jumbled up or if the order is changed for `sku`, I am not able to get appropriate data on the `stackedBarChartData`.

Now the response data is changed as such

```
  responseBarDataStacked = [
    { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Jun', value: 20 },
    { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Jun', value: 25 },
    { sku: 'Data 3', month: 'Jun', value: 35 },
    { sku: 'Data 5', month: 'Jun', value: 10 },
    { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Jul', value: 20 },
    { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Jul', value: 30 },
    { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Aug', value: 20 },
    { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Aug', value: 30 },
    { sku: 'Data 3', month: 'Aug', value: 15 },
    { sku: 'Data 4', month: 'Aug', value: 20 },
    { sku: 'Data 5', month: 'Aug', value: 15 }
  ];
```

As you may see

- there is no Data 4 for month of Jun
- there is no Data 3, Data 4, and Data 5 for month of Jul

For such case, expected value for stackedBarChartData is like this

```
[
  {data:[20, 25, 35, 10, null], label: 'Jun', stack: 'sameStack'},
  {data:[20, 30, null, null, null], label: 'Jun', stack: 'sameStack'},
  {data:[20, 30, 15, 15, 20], label: 'Jun', stack: 'sameStack'},
]
```

Note: If you see there in the first object's data, last value is null, this is because when uniquesku is create, the array will be like, This is because of FCFS used, and Data 5 comes before Data 4 in our API Response.

```
["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 5", "Data 4"]
```

For the ease, I have implemented it here to test.
[stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-stacked-lbxyes?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GaëlJ I have added details, please have a look at it again. Let me know if it is still not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all unique `sku` by using `array#map` and `Set`. Once you have this array, you can create an order object which will map `sku` with index, which will be used to assign value to data for a given `sku` value.

Now, using `array#reduce` you can group the data based on `month` and populate the `data` based on the `sku` value.

```js
const dataToFormat = [ { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Jun', value: 20 }, { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Jun', value: 25 }, { sku: 'Data 3', month: 'Jun', value: 35 }, { sku: 'Data 5', month: 'Jun', value: 10 }, { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Jul', value: 20 }, { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Jul', value: 30 }, { sku: 'Data 1', month: 'Aug', value: 20 }, { sku: 'Data 2', month: 'Aug', value: 30 }, { sku: 'Data 3', month: 'Aug', value: 15 }, { sku: 'Data 4', month: 'Aug', value: 20 }, { sku: 'Data 5', month: 'Aug', value: 15 } ],
      uniqueSku = [...new Set(dataToFormat.map(item => item.sku))],
      order = Object.fromEntries(uniqueSku.map((v,i) => ([v, i]))),
      result = Object.values(dataToFormat.reduce((r, {month, value, sku}) => {
        r[month] ||= {data: Array(uniqueSku.length).fill(null), label: month, stack: 'sameStack'};
        r[month].data[order[sku]] = value;
        return r;
      },{}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time, but the results are not as expected, if you see for month of June, I am getting only 4 data, and for month of July I am getting just 2. I have updated my question some extra details and expected results. Could you please look into that?

Comment: Can you check now if the solution is as per your expectation?

Comment: Now, if we look at the data for month of August, it should be `[data1, data2, data3, data5, data4]` first data5 and then data4 because uniqueSku will be set like that.

Comment: For Aug this would be `"data": [20,30,15,15,20]`

Comment: Please check now.

Comment: It looks great on the snippet, but when I try to implement it on my Stackblitz i am getting error check https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-stacked-lbxyes?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: It would be awesome if you could take some time explaining what you are doing on your code.

Comment: Added explanation too. Feel free to reach out if anything is not clear.